Microscopic level randomness

I have a fairly simple question but can't find any clear answer anywhere it seems.
Let's say you would isolate an unstable nucleus and just wait for it to decay. You would know of the decay by having some detectors somewhere catching some photons to acknowledge the decay.
Say that you start counting time as of $t_0$, and you observe the decay at $t_1$. Now let's run the thought experiment that you reverse time back to $t_0$, would you still observe the decay at exactly $t_1$? 
Does any theory back the answer to this? 
My personal opinion is that it would probably be different given the randomness of the event. But I'm not at all convinced by that reasoning, cause you could as well say that the underlying world is actually deterministic, and that it would therefore behave exactly in the same way given that all the initial conditions are perfectly identical. 
Cheers :)

The decay is indeed a random event, at least according to mainstream physics, so yeah, the time of the decay will not be the same. You also don't need to appeal to going back in time in order to perform the experiment under the same conditions. According to our current understanding, the laws of physics are invariant under time translations, i.e., assuming all external parameters are the same, performing an experiment now will yield the same result as performing it at a later time.


let's run the thought experiment that you reverse time back to $t_0$. What does it mean? How would we "reverse time back"?


@Damian basic equations (laws) have time translational invariance, but laws and initial conditions in QT do not determine experiment results. So the claim that performing the experiment at a different time with the same conditions would yield the same result (e.g. same spin projection, same light polarization) is groundless (also, it is unfalsifiable).

@JánLalinský Yes, you are right, the probabilities are the same but the measurements may give different results. That's what I wanted to say, since I also said that the time of the decay is not the same. However, the claim that the experiments yield the same results is easily falsifiable, and in fact wrong,  just perform an experiment twice under the same conditions and see that the results differ

@JánLalinský Actually, if you want to be rigorous, that claim may be in fact nonsensical since there is the possibility that you cannot have the same conditions at two different times (e.g. if one takes into account the time dependence of the scale factor in a FLRW cosmological metric)

@Damian Indeed, one can't reproduce all details, such as the microscopic state.

Given that nuclear decay is described by quantum mechanics, which is inherently random, even if the initial conditions are the same the time at which the nucleus decays won't be the same. The only thing you can calculate is the probability that it will decay at some time or another, and that agrees with the experimental observations to date. Of course you can say that the ''underlying world is deterministic'', and by that logic the time should be the same. The only problem with that logically sound reasoning is that simply does not seem to agree with experimental observations, which for some reason align with the weirdness of quantum mechanics. Therefore, the assumption that the ''underlying world is deterministic'' is (again, with our current understanding) incorrect.


does not seem to agree with experimental observations, which for some reason align with the weirdness of quantum mechanics. Only Bell's local causality is ruled out by experiments. Determinism in general is too broad and flexible, and is unfalsifiable. So one can believe in determinism without being in conflict with experiments. There is just no way to decide one way or the other. Of course, to this day, we do not have a working deterministic theory of nuclear decay.

